# overflow error when to assign value in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Assign value `300000` in the `cell(1,1)` :

```
Sub test()
   ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = 300000
End Sub
```

Now replace `300000` with `500*600`:

```
Sub test()
   ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = 500 * 600
End Sub
```

Why it encounter an error:overflow？

[image: overflow error]

Comment: Too many zeroes : 500 * 600 = 300000, which is much larger than 30000.

Comment: It is a typo,revised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Microsoft explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/overflow-error-6):

> You attempt to use a number in a calculation, and that number is coerced into an integer, but the result is larger than an integer. For example:

```
Dim x As Long 
x = 2000 * 365   ' Error: Overflow
```

> To work around this situation, type the number, like this:

```
Dim x As Long 
x = CLng(2000) * 365
```